# Cron Sphinx

Tags: sphinx, centos, сервер

Кто может поделиться скриптом под CentOS 6.5 для автоматического индексирования Sphinx?
Я попытался добавить в cron следующую строку:

```
*/5 * * * * indexer --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf --all --rotate
```

Так же пробовал пример [link text](https://toster.ru/q/68166)

Comment: Уже давно не трогал sphinx, деталей не помню и не знаю, что там сейчас.

Раньше была проблема: на больших данных полная индексация занимала много времени. RT-индексы тогда были [несколько ограничены](http://ruhighload.com/index.php/2010/08/18/sphinx-rt-real-time-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%8B/).

Но был выход: [использование delta-индексов](http://ruhighload.com/index.php/2009/06/25/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%B2-sphinx/) и последующее [слияние с main-индексом](http://ruhighload.com/index.php/2009/11/30/sphinxsearch-index-merging/)

Comment: На работе где-то были сохранены заметки по нему, когда попаду на работу (сейчас болею), тогда смогу поделиться набросками.

Но, возможно, мои заметки сейчас уже неактуальны, посмотрите - может, RT-индексы уже нормально работают

Comment: @BOPOH, так и не добрались до работы?